# Tomcat 8.5 - Cache warning flood

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, configuration

I am trying to migrate from Tomcat 8.0.37 to 8.5.6

In this new version, the `err` console is flooded constantly with these warnings:

```
oct. 27, 2016 3:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache getResource
WARNING: Unable to add the resource at [/WEB-INF/lib/something.jar] 
to the cache because there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries - 
consider increasing the maximum size of the cache
```

**I want to configure the servlet (web.xml or Spring) to ignore caching for some file types** (*.jar)

I've read about configuring the `context.xml` file but it feels like a workaround the real issue.

**how can I tell Tomcat to log everything to slf4j?**
I added this to the manifest but it doesn't work :

```
Dependencies: org.slf4j
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache warnings are caused by a known bug in 8.5.6 that will be fixed in 8.5.7. The new version should be available in a week or so.

If you want to use slf4j then following the slf4j instructions for redirecting java.util.logging output.